# Store/Save Predictive Model in R

Tags: r

I would like to store the output of the following code. I tried list, data frame and vector but was not able to store it.

```
Model<-lda( y ~ Trend+Class+F1+F4+ATR+macd_signal+macd1+F5 ,data=x)


> Model

Call:
lda(y ~ Trend + Class + F1 + F4 + ATR + macd_signal + macd1 + 
    F5, data = x)

Prior probabilities of groups:

     LOSS    PROFIT 
0.4981818 0.5018182 

Group means:

       TrendBull   ClassUP       F1       F4      ATR   macd_signal       macd1       F5
LOSS   0.5450122 0.3990268 1480.451 1481.672 11.64657 -0.0005850151  0.01542818 1478.567
PROFIT 0.5000000 0.4082126 1487.280 1486.707 12.25799 -0.0304256947 -0.03845741 1489.620

Coefficients of linear discriminants:

                     LD1
TrendBull   -0.033267160

ClassUP      0.151291378

F1          -0.003215276

F4          -0.042431558

ATR          0.082615338

macd_signal  0.090182055

macd1        2.637216918

F5           0.045956343

> class(Model)

[1] "lda"

> typeof(Model)

[1] "list"
```

Any ideas on how to store it?

Comment: what's wrong with `save`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing you can do is save the model output in its own file. An R object can be saved as an `rds` file. For example:

```
saveRDS(model, file = "your path/filename.rds")
```

You can then load the object into your R environment:

```
mod <- readRDS("your path/filename.rds")
```

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** `Model` is itself a list that contains all of the desired information and more. Run `str(Model)` to see its components. However, you can also extract just the information you want and save it in a list as follows:

```
my_lda_smry = function(x) {
  list(Call=x$call, Prior=x$prior, `Group Means`=x$means, 
     Coefficients=x$scaling,
     `Proportion of Trace`= round(x$svd^2/sum(x$svd^2), 4))
}

Model_summary = my_lda_smry(Model)
```

See below for additional explanation.

---

---

`Model` is an `lda` model object, which is a list containing all the output of the `lda` function. When you type `Model`, R is calling the `print` "method" for that lda model object, which is a function called `print.lda` (typing `Model` in the console is equivalent to typing `print(Model)`, which runs the `print.lda` function on your model object). So, you can look at the model object and the `print.lda` function to see what they're doing and then create your own summary object from that.

#### Look at code for `print.lda`

The code for `print.lda` is below. Note that `print.lda` is getting each of its outputs from the model object. For example `x$prior` is the prior probabilities of each group. We just need to create a function to extract each of elements we want.

```
getAnywhere(print.lda)
```

> ```
> function (x, ...) 
> {
>     if (!is.null(cl <- x$call)) {
>         names(cl)[2L] <- ""
>         cat("Call:\n")
>         dput(cl, control = NULL)
>     }
>     cat("\nPrior probabilities of groups:\n")
>     print(x$prior, ...)
>     cat("\nGroup means:\n")
>     print(x$means, ...)
>     cat("\nCoefficients of linear discriminants:\n")
>     print(x$scaling, ...)
>     svd <- x$svd
>     names(svd) <- dimnames(x$scaling)[[2L]]
>     if (length(svd) > 1L) {
>         cat("\nProportion of trace:\n")
>         print(round(svd^2/sum(svd^2), 4L), ...)
>     }
>     invisible(x)
> }
> ```

#### Look at the model object returned by `lda`

Now let's create a model and look at the model object. We don't actually need to do look at the model object here, because `print.lda` tells us what we need to know. However, knowing the structure of the model object can be helpful if you want to extract information that isn't returned by the standard extractor functions provided with a package. Note the the model object is a list containing various types of information about the model.

```
library(MASS)

model = lda(mpg ~ wt + hp + carb + cyl, data=mtcars)

str(model)
```

> ```
> List of 10
>  $ prior  : Named num [1:25] 0.0625 0.0312 0.0312 0.0312 0.0312 ...
>   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:25] "10.4" "13.3" "14.3" "14.7" ...
>  $ counts : Named int [1:25] 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
>   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:25] "10.4" "13.3" "14.3" "14.7" ...
>  $ means  : num [1:25, 1:4] 5.34 3.84 3.57 5.34 3.57 ...
>   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
>   .. ..$ : chr [1:25] "10.4" "13.3" "14.3" "14.7" ...
>   .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "wt" "hp" "carb" "cyl"
>  $ scaling: num [1:4, 1:4] 4.668 -0.0115 -3.6744 -3.8415 4.2625 ...
>   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
>   .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "wt" "hp" "carb" "cyl"
>   .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "LD1" "LD2" "LD3" "LD4"
>  $ lev    : chr [1:25] "10.4" "13.3" "14.3" "14.7" ...
>  $ svd    : num [1:4] 10.51 3.42 1.49 1.05
>  $ N      : int 32
>  $ call   : language lda(formula = mpg ~ wt + hp + carb + cyl, data = mtcars)
>  $ terms  :Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language mpg ~ wt + hp + carb + cyl
>   .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(mpg, wt, hp, carb, cyl)
>   .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:5, 1:4] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
>   .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
>   .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "mpg" "wt" "hp" "carb" ...
>   .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "wt" "hp" "carb" "cyl"
>   .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:4] "wt" "hp" "carb" "cyl"
>   .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:4] 1 1 1 1
>   .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
>   .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
>   .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
>   .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(mpg, wt, hp, carb, cyl)
>   .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:5] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" ...
>   .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "mpg" "wt" "hp" "carb" ...
>  $ xlevels: Named list()
>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "lda"
> ```

#### Extract the information we want and return it in a list

The function below just mimics what `print.lda` does, but saves the results in a list, rather than printing it to the screen:

```
my_lda_smry = function(x) {
  list(Call=x$call, Prior=x$prior, `Group Means`=x$means, 
     Coefficients=x$scaling,
     `Proportion of Trace`= round(x$svd^2/sum(x$svd^2), 4))
}
```

Now run the function:

```
m.smry = my_lda_smry(model)
```

> ```
> $Call
> lda(formula = mpg ~ wt + hp + carb + cyl, data = mtcars)
>
> $Prior
>    10.4    13.3    14.3    14.7      15    15.2    15.5    15.8    16.4    17.3    17.8    18.1    18.7    19.2    19.7      21 
> 0.06250 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.06250 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.06250 0.03125 0.06250 
>    21.4    21.5    22.8    24.4      26    27.3    30.4    32.4    33.9 
> 0.06250 0.03125 0.06250 0.03125 0.03125 0.03125 0.06250 0.03125 0.03125 
>
> $`Group Means`
>          wt    hp carb cyl
> 10.4 5.3370 210.0  4.0   8
> 13.3 3.8400 245.0  4.0   8
> 14.3 3.5700 245.0  4.0   8
> 14.7 5.3450 230.0  4.0   8
> 15   3.5700 335.0  8.0   8
> 15.2 3.6075 165.0  2.5   8
> 15.5 3.5200 150.0  2.0   8
> 15.8 3.1700 264.0  4.0   8
> 16.4 4.0700 180.0  3.0   8
> 17.3 3.7300 180.0  3.0   8
> 17.8 3.4400 123.0  4.0   6
> 18.1 3.4600 105.0  1.0   6
> 18.7 3.4400 175.0  2.0   8
> 19.2 3.6425 149.0  3.0   7
> 19.7 2.7700 175.0  6.0   6
> 21   2.7475 110.0  4.0   6
> 21.4 2.9975 109.5  1.5   5
> 21.5 2.4650  97.0  1.0   4
> 22.8 2.7350  94.0  1.5   4
> 24.4 3.1900  62.0  2.0   4
> 26   2.1400  91.0  2.0   4
> 27.3 1.9350  66.0  1.0   4
> 30.4 1.5640  82.5  2.0   4
> 32.4 2.2000  66.0  1.0   4
> 33.9 1.8350  65.0  1.0   4
>
> $Coefficients
>              LD1          LD2         LD3         LD4
> wt    4.66796895  4.262520788  0.35307402 -0.67013561
> hp   -0.01149489  0.005714994  0.04376624  0.01627358
> carb -3.67441417 -0.581458148 -0.44870373 -0.83522067
> cyl  -3.84149993 -0.911662765 -1.52258858  0.37350681
>
> $`Proportion of Trace`
> [1] 0.8804 0.0930 0.0178 0.0088
> ```